# How do I use Ruby metaprogramming to add callbacks to a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I wrote a simple Cacheable module that makes it simple to cache aggregate fields in a parent model. The module requires that the parent object implement the `cacheable` method and a `calc_` method for each field that requires caching at the parent level.

```
module Cacheable
  def cache!(fields, *objects)
    objects.each do |object|
      if object.cacheable?
        calc(fields, objects)
        save!(objects)
      end
    end
  end

  def calc(fields, objects)
    fields.each { |field| objects.each(&:"calc_#{field}") }
  end

  def save!(objects)
    objects.each(&:save!)
  end
end
```

I would like to add callbacks to the ActiveRecord model into which this module is included. This method would require that the model implement a hash of parent models and field names that require caching.

```
def cachebacks(klass, parents)
  [:after_save, :after_destroy].each do |callback|
    self.send(callback, proc { cache!(CACHEABLE[klass], self.send(parents)) })
  end
end
```

This approach works great if I manually add both callbacks using such as:

```
after_save proc { cache!(CACHEABLE[Quote], *quotes.all) }
after_destroy proc { cache!(CACHEABLE[Quote], *quotes.all) }
```

But, I'm receiving the following error when I try to use the `cachebacks` method to add these to callbacks.

```
cachebacks(Quote, "*quotes.all")

NoMethodError: undefined method `cachebacks' for #<Class:0x007fe7be3f2ae8>
```

How do I add these callbacks to the class dynamically?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't make sense out of the last part. Is `Quote` a related model? Could you please post how your class looks like right now?

Comment: The answer that I worked out based on your tip should explain things. I'm also interested in the ActiveSupport::Concern approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a good case for [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html). You can tweak your `cachebacks` method slightly to add it as a class method on the including class:

```
module Cacheable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def cachebacks(&block)
      klass = self
      [:after_save, :after_destroy].each do |callback|
        self.send(callback, proc { cache!(CACHEABLE[klass], *klass.instance_eval(&block)) })
      end
    end
  end

  def cache!(fields, *objects)
    # ...
  end

  # ...
end
```

To use it:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Cacheable
  cachebacks { all }
end
```

The block you pass to `cachebacks` will be executed in the context of the class that's calling it. In this example, `{ all }` is equivalent to calling `Example.all` and passing the results into your `cache!` method.

---

To answer your question in the comments, `Concern` encapsulates a common pattern and establishes a convention in Rails. The syntax is slightly more elegant:

```
included do
  # behaviors
end

# instead of

def self.included(base)
  base.class_eval do
    # behaviors
  end
end
```

It also takes advantage of another convention to automatically and correctly include class and instance methods. If you namespace those methods in modules named `ClassMethods` and `InstanceMethods` (although as you've seen, `InstanceMethods` is optional), then you're done.

Last of all, it handles module dependencies. The documentation gives a good example of this, but in essence, it prevents the including class from having to explicitly include dependent modules in addition to the module it's actually interested in.

Comment: That's a good looking solution. I haven't used ActiveSupport::Concerns before. What are the key benefits over an approach like the one that I posted below (the Cacheable module)?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more details about `Concern`.

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks to Brandon for the answer that helped me write the solution.**

Add the following to your model. You can `cacheback` multiple parent relationships per model. You can also specify different attribute names for the parent and child tables by passing in a hash instead of a string for a particular field.

```
include Cacheable
cacheback(parent: :quotes, fields: %w(weight pallet_spots value equipment_type_id))
```

This module extends ActiveSupport::Concern and adds the callbacks and performs the cacheing. Your parent classes will need to implement `calc_field` methods to do the caching work.

```
module Cacheable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def cacheback(options)
      fields = Cacheable.normalize_fields(options[:fields])
      [:after_save, :after_destroy].each do |callback|
        self.send(callback, proc { cache!(fields, self.send(options[:parent])) })
      end
    end
  end

  def cache!(fields, objects)
    objects = objects.respond_to?(:to_a) ? objects.to_a : [objects]
    objects.each do |object|
      if object.cacheable?
        calc(fields, objects)
        save!(objects)
      end
    end
  end

  def calc(fields, objects)
    fields.each do |parent_field, child_field|
      objects.each(&:"calc_#{parent_field}") if self.send("#{child_field}_changed?".to_sym)
    end
  end

  def save!(objects)
    objects.each { |object| object.save! if object.changed? }
  end

  def self.normalize_fields(fields)
    Hash[fields.collect { |f| f.is_a?(Hash) ? f.to_a : [f, f] }]
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, I might not be right if I didn't understand your question. Would this work for you?

```
module Cacheable
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def self.cachebacks(klass, parents)
        [:after_save, :after_destroy].each do |callback|
          self.send(callback, proc { cache!(CACHEABLE[klass], self.send(parents)) })
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def cache!(fields, *objects)
    objects.each do |object|
      if object.cacheable?
        calc(fields, objects)
        save!(objects)
      end
    end
  end

  def calc(fields, objects)
    fields.each { |field| objects.each(&:"calc_#{field}") }
  end

  def save!(objects)
    objects.each(&:save!)
  end
end
```

Comment: While it wasn't exactly the solution, your answer helped me figure it out. I'll add the complete solution below as a separate answer. If you  adjust yours I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks so much.