# Ruby on Rails - Callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I've been tasked to implement a very basic feature request for a Rails application (Foreman), and have stumbled across an issue that seems to be both very basic and a very popular issue. Coming from a Java background, I find callbacks do not work as I would normally expect.

Normally in Java when listeners are used, you can subscribe arbitrary pieces of code to the event, and when the event fires the object iterates over the listeners and notifies each one. A very basic example would be:

```
public class Foo {
    private List<FooListener> foo_list = new List<FooListener>();
    public void add_foo_listener(FooListener fooListener){
        this.foo_list.add(fooListener);
    }
    private void on_foo_thing(){
        foreach(foo : foo_list) {
            fooListener.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

So you can add however many listeners from external classes by calling "add_foo_listener(fooListener)" which will be notified when the on_foo_thing() method is called - without any modification to the original class.

Is there anything similar in ruby/rails? The class I want to hook into has the following hooks defined:

```
define_model_callbacks :build, :only => :after
define_model_callbacks :provision, :only => :before

# Custom hooks will be executed after_commit
after_commit :build_hooks, :if => :persisted?

def build_hooks
    return unless respond_to?(:old) && old && (build? != old.build?)
    if build?
      run_callbacks :build do
        logger.debug { "custom hook after_build on #{name} will be executed if defined." }
      end
    else
      run_callbacks :provision do
        logger.debug { "custom hook before_provision on #{name} will be executed if defined." }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use Ruby metaprogramming to add callbacks to a Rails model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084234/how-do-i-use-ruby-metaprogramming-to-add-callbacks-to-a-rails-model)

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understand of ActiveSupport::Concern I would have to edit the original class definition to include my Concern class, which this answer seems to re-enforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the possible duplicate is correct, in order to alter a model in rails without editing that models code to explicitly include the listened, you to use the following:

```
Host::Managed.send(:include, ::HostExtensions::ManagedHost)
```

Which is telling the Host::Managed class that it should include the HostExtensions::ManagedHost module at runtime.

And for completeness sake, if you're doing this in a Rails App you may need to add something like this to your Engine class (engine.rb):

```
config.to_prepare do
  require File.expand_path('../../../app/models/concerns/host_extensions/managedhost', __FILE__)
  Host::Managed.send(:include, ::HostExtensions::ManagedHost)
end
```